# how i can change code from var array to code from json?

Tags: javascript, php, html

hi i need help to write a format code. i write javascript code to parse json and use the data, the json file contain latitude and longtitude data :

```
const api_url = 'json.php'
        async function getjsonlatest() {
            const response = await fetch(api_url);
            const data = await response.json();
            
            const latitude = data.map(loc => loc.latitude)
            const longitude = data.map(loc => loc.longtitude)
            
            var latlngs = [
                            [-7.3248841543504, 112.63356271278819],        
                            [-7.354508491243568, 112.62849870236622]       
                                                                    ];
            var polyline = L.polyline(latlngs, {color: 'green'}).addTo(mymap);
```

my question is how i can change :

```
var latlngs = [
                        [-7.3248841543504, 112.63356271278819],        
                        [-7.354508491243568, 112.62849870236622]       
                                                                ];
```

with data from :

```
const latitude = data.map(loc => loc.latitude)
const longitude = data.map(loc => loc.longtitude)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const latlngs = data.map(loc => ([loc.latitude, loc.longitude])
```

You can return array from your map function building array of corteges.